# Partitioning set of objects

Tags: algorithm, optimization, partitioning, bin-packing

I am trying to partition a set of 100 objects into two subsets. Each object has a set of numeric attributes.

The current objective function is to minimize the average of the difference between averages of the attributes of each set. In other words, we first calculate the average of each attribute in each set, then take the difference of each attribute between sets, and then finally take the average of those differences.

Note that this objective function is one of several used (and is the simplest); I need a general solution that works regardless of how objective function is calculated.

The solutions I've come up with are fairly rudimentary:

- Use a greedy algorithm to iteratively add a new object to one of the subsets
- Same as above, but allow backtracking to rebalance the subsets after each new allocation
- Start off with fully seeded sets (based on random assignment), and then doing a greedy search to move an object from one set to the other if it lowers the objective function.

Are there any more accurate methods than these; i.e. that will result in more closely matched sets but do not take exceptionally long to evaluate?

Comment: The second bullet seems like a good balance between accuracy and speed.  As you correctly infer, the first bullet is probably the least accurate, while the third bullet strikes me as the most accurate, but having the performance characteristics of an insertion sort.

Comment: The answer to your last sentence depends on what you mean by "efficient;" are your proposed methods all too slow?  How much improvement do you need? Have you profiled your code to see how well it performs currently?

Comment: Can you explain "minimize mean difference between attributes?".  Do you want for each attribute, the sum of the values on one side of the partition to be as close to the other as possible?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your objective function? Do you take the mean of differences over all attributes and pairs sharing a partition?

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the question to reflect that I'm looking for a more accurate answer (that is not brute forced). The definition of the objective function has been updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is an answer that's provably better. You could start with k-means, which is at least a systematic version of your second approach, or genetic optimization as a more systematic version of your third approach. In any case, look at some classification alggorithms and see what fits your case.

If you want to prove anything, then in the end, the dimensionality of your attributes might be the key:

If you have just one numeric attribute, the solution is straightforward. If you have many attributes and sufficiently uniform distribution, not partition can be "good". Try to partition hypercubes in two halves using your metric to get a feeling.

In other cases, there might be a geometric solution by projecting the points onto one dimension, preserving distances as good as possible. One approach to do so is multidimensional scaling (MDS).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am looking for a solution that allows me to change the objective function. The one provided was the simplest case I picked; some involve reducing the Kolmogorov–Smirnov distance across dimensions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your objective function correctly, is seems like you can calculate a cost for each object directly.  Make a single pass over the data to calculate the mean value of each attribute.
 Then `cost(obj) := sum( [ obj.attr[i]-mean[i] for i in len(obj.attr) ])`

This reduces the problem to the [Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is well studied.

You might need to normalize each value to a percent of observed range in order to prevent a wide-ranged attribute from dominating the decision. The range can be found in the same pass as the mean.

Comment: The objective function in the description is just one of several that we use (it was chosen because it is the simplest). I need a general solution that will work for any objective function.